# sqlite match table 1 with table 2 id column and output data

Tags: database, sqlite

I need to retrieve all data on a database with two tables,
the `MAIN` table have an column `LOC_ID` with an numerical id stored, and some more columns like `USERNAME`,`COMMENTS`,
the second table `LOC` have and `ID` column, and more columns like `IPADDRESS`, `MACADDRESS`, the `ID` Column in `LOC` table match the `LOC_IC` column data of `MAIN` table

I would like to retrieve all information with a command similar to `SELECT * FROM MAIN` but I want the `LOC_ID` data replaced or together with the `LOC` tables data but matched with the `LOC_IC <=> IC`

> Table MAIN

```
LOC_IC  USERNAME   COMMENTS
5120    admin      administrator
5125    user3      n/a
```

> Table LOC

```
ID      IPADDRESS     MACADDRESS
5120    127.0.0.1     00:00:00:00:00:00
5121    192.168.0.99  00:00:00:00:00:CC
5125    192.168.0.23  HE:LP:PL:EA:SE:=D
```

Comment: Please provide your desired output for this example data.

Comment: maybe another table with the columns populated like this?
`LOC_IC  USERNAME  COMMENTS    IPADDRESS      MACADDRESS`

Comment: And what is the desired output? You wanted *all* data, what about LOC 5121?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [`JOIN`](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)?

```sql
SELECT loc_ic, username, comments, ipaddress, macaddress
  FROM main m JOIN loc l
    ON m.loc_ic = l.id;
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=a910e8c838a3de5b93fcdd92de3a671a) demo

Output:

```
 LOC_IC | USERNAME | COMMENTS      | IPADDRESS    | MACADDRESS       
 ------ | -------- | ------------- | ------------ | -----------------
 5120   | admin    | administrator | 127.0.0.1    | 00:00:00:00:00:00
 5125   | user3    | n/a           | 192.168.0.23 | HE:LP:PL:EA:SE:=D
```